# Trapezoidal area under multiple peaks in Python

Tags: python, signals, physics, area

I am trying to integrate the area of multiple peaks in Python. I am measuring different amplitudes of signals from an oscilloscope and managed to plot them as a function of time as shown here

[image: Amplitudes as a function of time.].

I am trying now to use trapezoidal area function for each peak in order to plot area distribution as a function of count. I have written this code but there is no results.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from readTrc import Trc
from numpy import trapz

trc = Trc()

fName = "./Am.trc"

datX, datY, d = trc.open(fName)

y = np.reshape(datY, (10000,4002))
for i in range(10000):
    plt.plot(y[i,:])  # Here to get all amplitudes as a function of time

area = trapz(datX, datY)
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I accomplish this?

Comment: [`trapz()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) is expecting `(y, x)` not `(x, y)`. It also defaults to integrating along the last `axis` so if you have a 2D array it will integrate along the second axis.